# Bruteforce 7z archive with a password list

Tags: python, 7zip

I have a 7z file and a password list.

I want to bruteforce that file with that list.

I use Windows 10, Python 3.11.1 and 7z 22.1.0.0

My code:

```
path_7z: str = "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe"
with open("passwords.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    for pw in file:
        pw = pw.rstrip("/n")
        #call 7z with parameter {filepath} and {pw}, unpack archive if {pw} is correct, otherwise continue with the next {pw}
```

How can I do the part in the last line?

Comment: Are you looking for the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module?

Comment: Unrelated, `/n` doesn't mean what you want there.

Comment: Have you tried [pyunpack](https://github.com/ponty/pyunpack/tree/0.3)